# What the right way to make this kind of complicated request over ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

Lets say we have follow models:

```
class Bundle(models.Model):
    # ...

class Order(models.Model):
    # ...
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(
        Bundle, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('бандл'), 
        related_name='orders')

class CommentThread(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'),
        blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('last time thread was read'), default=None,
                                    null=True, blank=True)

class Comments(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'),
        blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))

    text = models.TextField(max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), default=None, db_index=True)
```

By design, we may attach comments to everyone models, but in this case, we attach comments to `Bundle` over content type \ object id generics. To implement "read \ unread comments for each user in the thread" we use `CommentThread` model with the same content type object generic (I know, this is terrible idea, but this is kind of legacy code).

If Bundle instance have attached comments with `comment.submit_date` > `comment_thread.objects.filter(user=user, content_object=bundle).datetime`this mean comment is new for current user.

So, I need to get list of `Orders` with new comments for user, ordered by time of submitting last comment, attached to `Order.bundle` with count of this comments for each `Order`

Question is: what the right way make this request by ORM? Is it possible?